# How can we programmatically control the screen orientation in secondary displays?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-screen-support, external-display

I am handling secondary display from an application developed in the Android Studio using [presentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation) class. Now I want to control the `screen orientation` like setting `portrait` and `landscape`. I am able to set the `orientation` for the primary display but not the secondary display. 
My XML file is covering the entire display not according to orientation. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `onConfigurationChanged` Override method will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether will this work, just give it a try. since [Presentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation) is a [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog), you may not be able to handle rotation of it. but you can handle the rotation of its base activity. which might affect the rotation of presentation.

Hope this helps!